# Add wordpress database data to a varible

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to resolve the following -

```
 $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table name WHERE ID = 1" ); 
 foreach ( $result as $print ) {
     print '<div class = "facebook">facebook link<a href = "facebook.com/' .$print->Facebook. '"></a></div>';
 }
```

This should display the **facebook** link and link towards the correct page but unfortunately doesn't work as it removes the link.

I hope i'm not doing this completely wrong as I used a foreach loop as I will be adding other social media.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will be able to test these answers once home. I got the result to show ie in the database under the facebook col "test" is an example field which shows but just doesn't link.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:
Use `get_results()` as you did:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->table_name WHERE id = 1"); 
foreach ( $results as $result )
    { echo $result->column_name }
```

OR

Use `get_rows()`:

```
$mylink = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->table_name WHERE link_id = 10", ARRAY_A );
echo $mylink['column_name'];
```

You can see more here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `global $wpdb` ?

Use it like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM $wpdb->table name WHERE ID = 1');
```

Check this [official doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The link is just not visible because your `a` tag doesn't contain any text.

Change this:

```html
<div class = "facebook">facebook link<a href = "facebook.com/' .$print->Facebook. '"></a></div>
```

to this:

```html
<div class = "facebook"><a href = "facebook.com/' .$print->Facebook. '">facebook link</a></div>
```

(move the text inside of the `a` tag).